# How can I remove elevated permissions from snap-confine?

Tags: permissions, 19.10, snap, anbox

I installed anbox by running the command `sudo snap install --devmode --edge anbox`. After it installed, I tried running it from the search box, and nothing happened when I clicked it. The I opened terminal and ran `anbox launch` and got `snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks`. How can I fix this?

Comment: "After installation, the channel being tracked can be changed with: `sudo snap switch --channel=stable snap_package_name`" from https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started

Comment: @DKBose Anbox only uses beta and edge channels https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install.html

Comment: Okay! But that page is from 2018. Maybe "At the moment we require the use of –devmode as the Anbox snap is not yet fully confined. Work has started with the upstream snapd project to get support for full confinement." has changed and you don't need --devmode now? Just guessing!